# relationship between number of LSTM cells and number of time series

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I have a project to predict a output value from a set of time series input using Keras' sequential model with LSTM cells.

my input training data has a shape of (10000, 500, 3) where
10000 is the number of samples, 
500 is the number of time series, 
3 is the number of features. 
My output is at time 500. My model looks like below.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(256, input_shape=(train_X.shape[1], train_X.shape[2])))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear', bias_initializer=k.initializers.Constant(0.1)))
model.compile(loss='mae', optimizer='adam')
```

Let's say I know the input values at time 0 through 500 have an effect on the output at time 500. In that case, should I have the number of LSTM cells to be 500 (instead of 256 in my current model)? Also, does it make sense to have LSTM cells more than 500 when the number of time series is 500? I've seen other examples where the number of LSTM cells exceeds the number of time series (and vice versa). I'd like to know what's the best practice.

Comment: Isn’t this more of a statistics/machine learning question than a programming one?

Comment: LSTM `units` and the length of the time series has nothing to do with each other. If you have an `n` long time series and `m` LSTM units, it simply means that the LSTM will produces `m` outputs at every step of the `n` long sample.